# Posted on the wrong site

Tags: discussion, moving-questions

I may have posted my question on the wrong site.  I'm not sure.  What is the process to move my question to ServerFault instead of superuser?
[Trouble connecting to MySQL in a local Docker on a Mac](https://superuser.com/questions/1124801/trouble-connecting-to-mysql-in-a-local-docker-on-a-mac)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty sure its on topic here. SF would kick it back if we migrated it. Its a developer issue rather than a aysadmin issue.

Comment: Would it be better on SO?

Comment: Docker? No, they'd kick it over to SF, if enough people who don't know better vote.